# I'm trying to use Sum() over(partition by ) to find the difference between two groups of numbers and I'm getting an unexpected result

Tags: sql, analytics, window-functions, impala

I'm using sql and tableau to create a burn down chart. I wrote a sql query that does most of the calculation for me. I have a table structure that looks like this

| ld.cal_dt | ld.camp_name | ld.ld_cnt | dy_cmp.cal_dt | dy_cmp.camp_name | dy_comp.com_cnt | brndn |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-09-05 | Ex-000010 | 62 | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL |
| 2023-09-06 | Ex-000010 | 0 | 2023-09-06 | Ex-000010 | 54 | -54 |
| 2023-09-08 | Ex-000010 | 0 | 2023-09-08 | Ex-000010 | 1 | -55 |

Below is what the relevant part of my query looks like

```
select  lc.calendardate,
        lc.campaign_name,
        lc.loaded_count,
        dcc.calendardate,
        dcc.campaign_name,
        dcc.completed_call_count,
        sum(cast(lc.loaded_count as int) - cast(dcc.completed_call_count as int)) over(partition by lc.campaign_name order by lc.calendardate asc) as burn_down
from adjusted_loaded_count as lc
left join adjusted_daily_calls_completed as dcc on
    lc.calendardate = dcc.calendardate and
    lc.campaign_name = dcc.campaign_name
where lc.campaign_name is not null
```

I'm getting unexpected results in my burndown column. I expect the result to be 8 and then 7 instead of -54 and -55. Why aren't I actually getting the difference between the two numbers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Three rows:

| ld_cnt | com_cnt | diff | sum so far |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 62 | NULL | NULL | NULL |
| 0 | 54 | -54 | -54 |
| 0 | 1 | -1 | -55 |

You want

| ld_cnt | com_cnt | diff | sum so far |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 62 | treat NULL as 0 | 0 | 62 |
| 0 | 54 | -54 | 8 |
| 0 | 1 | -1 | 7 |

You want to treat NULLs as zeros. Use `COALESCE` for this:

```
SUM(
  COALESCE(CAST(lc.loaded_count as int), 0) - 
  COALESCE(CAST(dcc.completed_call_count as int), 0)
) OVER (PARTITION BY lc.campaign_name 
        ORDER BY lc.calendardate ASC) AS burn_down
```